# Access date VBA else if statement only showing one

Tags: vba, datetime, ms-access, if-statement, null

I have a form where i retrieve the start date and ending date from a table in access.

The start date and end date are both known as startdate and endate.
Then i have another column which is status.

My code is like this:

```
sd = Me.startdate
ed = Me.enddate
DateValue (sd)
DateValue (ed)

If IsNull(sd And ed) Or (ed > Date) Then
Me.Text59 = "In use"

ElseIf (ed < Date) Then
Me.Text59 = "Free"
```

so basically what i wanted to do is, if the end date is earlier than today, the status will display it as Free. However, if the end date is later than today, the status will be in use. columns where the start date and end date are empty will be displayed as in use too.

My table's start date and end date are in date/time data type.

When the code runs, they only display "In use" when clearly some of my dates end earlier than today! Help please ):

Comment: Your DateValue lines will return values, but they aren't saved anywhere.
have you tried putting the DateValue in the If condition?
If IsNull(sd And ed) Or (Datevalue(ed) > Date) Then

Comment: @gizlmeier yeap i did! it was the same result which only displays "in use" in all the rows

Comment: This is strange, for me the date comparison works fine if i try DateValue("2016-04-23") > Now for example. What if you try to change the ElseIf to an Else?

Comment: have you tried this ? ->  (isNull(sd) And isNull(ed)) Or (DateValue(ed) > Date)

Comment: @gizlmeier i change to to else and it still does nto work

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo i tried it just and the results returned the same

Comment: okay, then it has to do with the date Format, can you post an example of sd and ed ?

Comment: start date 3/18/2016 . end date 3/18/2016. both have control source linked to the table. and thier format is general date. @DoktorOSwaldo

Comment: have you put DateValue in the else to ? it works fine on my macro... have you tried to "MsgBox Datevalue(ed) < Date " ?

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo yeah i did put the datevalue in else. i have alot of records in the form so i dont think i should use message box

Comment: @user6239244 sorry debug.print is better anyway ;)

Comment: How is this code called? Please provide the full function.

Comment: what type of form is this, i.e. datasheet/continuous etc.? cant you just run an update query?

Comment: @Andre its a click button

Comment: @LiamH its a multiple item forms. I have a field which i do not wish for it to be in the table so i use form

Answer (score 0):

You are not telling if either startdate or enddate can be Null while the other is not, so both will either be Null or hold a value. Further, startdate seems to always be earlier than enddate, thus of no importance.

Then:

```
Dim sd As Variant
Dim ed As Variant
Dim inuse As Boolean

sd = Me!startdate
ed = Me!enddate

If IsNull(sd) And IsNull(ed) Then
    inuse = True
ElseIf DateDiff("d", Date, ed) > 0 Then
    inuse = True
End If

If inuse = True Then
    Me!Text59 = "In use"
Else
    Me!Text59 = "Free"
End If
```

For a single-line code to use as *ControlSource* for *Text59* (Nz is only used to avoid an error if `ed` is Null):

```
=IIf(IsNull([startdate]+[enddate]),"In use",IIf(DateDiff("d",Date(),Nz(ed, Date()))>0,"In use","Free"))
```

Comment: Hi this is currently working but its only updating the fields one by one and i have to click the button for each field to be updated. is there anyway to click the button once and update all the fields in the form. im using a multiple items form

Comment: This is currently working but it only updates the first field in the form. how do i make it such taht when i click the button, it updates all the fields in the table.

Comment: As this can calculated at any time, you shouldn't store it as a value in a field but have a query that returns the status, or just display the current status in the form.